# how to dynamically get the server IP of rds instance created in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I am using the terraform module at source `terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws` to create an rds instance based on postgresql in terraform. As part of this project I also wish to create roles within the postgresql database with specific permissions. I know there is a postresql provider which I can include as follows:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  host            = "postgres_server_ip"
  port            = 5432
  database        = "postgres"
  username        = "postgres_user"
  password        = "postgres_password"
  sslmode         = "require"
  connect_timeout = 15
}
```

However, for the host I will need to somehow access the server IP of the RDS instance just created - does anyone know how to do this when using the RDS module with the source I have mentioned above?

Comment: you may need to create a wrapper script and use the outputs from that module & if you're in a bash terminal for example, you can run this cmd: `terraform output db_instance_address` to obtain the instance ip after it's created.

Comment: You should always use the DNS name for accessing RDS instances. The IP address is not guaranteed to be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the postgres IP a DNS Name will also work.

The module in question has an output parameter named. `db_instance_endpoint`

```
module "rds" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "5.2.3"
  # Your variables
}

#You can use that variable using

locals {
   the_result = module.rds.db_instance_endpoint
}
```

The problem you are going to face is that a [provider block cannot come from dynamic values such as resources or modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration).  They can come from input variables.  So to pull this off place your postgres code in its own terraform module.

And pass the host in as a variable which is allowed.